# NameError: undefined local variable or method `sRails' for main:Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I can not find this 'sRails' error. I just started using this stuff 2 days ago. Sorry, if it seems like I didn't look. I looked for a while on this site and I can't seem to find it. I tried to find 'sRails' in my code, and I just cant seem to find it.

I'm getting this error when attempting to upload to heroku.

https://github.com/thenile123/pinteresting

Answer (score 1):

I went to your github link there and searched the project for `sRails` and got this result: https://github.com/thenile123/pinteresting/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sRails

So looks like that's your problem. Should be just `Rails` (without the `s` in front).